# Get push notifications when PhpMyAdmin table row changes (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created an app like Uber, I want to receive a push notification, when a row changes in PhpMyAdmin database, how can I do it ? I have read that I should use WebSocket in Flutter, but I don't know how to config my server with php, when row changes I get some push notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very broad question.
One of the ways to achieve what you want could be the following.

1. You should look into push notification services like [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/), [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging), etc.
2. Suppose you picked Service `A`. Now in your backend, whenever you insert a row, send a push notification to the frontend.
   This can be found in the documentation of Service `A`.

Something like this if it uses REST APIs:

```js
http.post(
  url: ...
  body: {
   ...
 }
)
```

3. In the frontend (`flutter`), have a listener for this notification (web socket, a client package in pubspec, etc.)

Comment: Thank you very muchh you helped me!!!!